# running a token for two things

Tags: python, discord.py

so I'm trying to create a bot for my dis server however two parts of my code requires the token to run them however no matter my efforts I have not been able to run both with the token.

my code:

```
intents = discord.Intents(members=True, messages = True, guilds=True,)


client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
    
BOT_PREFIX = ("!")  
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=BOT_PREFIX)

client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

is it even possible to run both the bot and the client?  if possible how would i go about running them both with the token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you're attempting to run two instances, one with only intents and another as a bot without intents, you don't need a separate `client` and `bot`. Just use one:

```py
BOT_PREFIX = ("!")
intents = discord.Intents(members = True, messages = True, guilds = True)

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = BOT_PREFIX, intents = intents)

client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

Now you can define commands or events with `@client.command` or `@client.event`. If you'd rather use `bot`, then change `client` everywhere to `bot`, but don't use both.